# Full disk encryption (FDE) options for Kubuntu

Tags: linux, encryption, kubuntu, fde

I'm working towards switching to Linux (Kubuntu) and am currently researching FDE options. I'm currently a Windows user with Veracrypt FDE. So far I've come across dm-crypt and LUKS. I have no idea what they are and how they work. My main concern is how secure these and other options are and whether they have undergone security audits? How do they compare to Veracrypt for Windows (since it can't do FDE on Linux)?

Comment: You might want to review some of the questions related to LUKS over on the security site.  https://security.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=luks

Answer (score 1):

The Kubuntu installer includes the option to do full disk encryption(*) with LUKS (your whole system is encrypted)(this is what I'm using...).

LUKS is about as good as it gets when it comes to disk encryption.

(*) caution, when you enter the first key the keyboard is mapped to QWERTY US. If you are using a different layout, better enter a simple layout-agnostic key at that point and change it later with a real key (the real keyboard layout will be used it all other cases).

Comment: So has there been a security audit of LUKS? Also when generating the key Veracrypt uses the random movement of the mouse, while LUKS doesn't seem to have that feature - isn't that a major problem for generating enough randomness?

Comment: `ses the random movement of the mouse, while LUKS doesn't seem to have that feature - isn't that a major problem for generating enough randomness?` - Pretty sure it uses [/dev/random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) for creating the volume keys, and /dev/random is seeded by system activity.